# Ping and nslookup work, browsing doesn't

Tags: networking, dns, windows-8.1, ping, nslookup

I have a problem with my desktop computer. I can execute ping and nslookup commands but browsing doesn't work well. It takes a very long time to open webpages.

I have tried different browsers, different cables, different network cards (the one built in my motherboard and an external A-Link NA1GHR). I also reinstalled my Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit OS and downloaded all the drivers for my Asus P8P67 motherboard, including the network drivers.

What should I try next?

This problem doesn't occur in local network. I can download files from my server downstairs just fine

Comment: what are the results of ping to several web-servers? How about traceroute to the same websites? You need to look at the route you are taking and the ms latency to various points. Do you see the same issues if you plug directly into your ISP provided device and not through your network? Do you see latency to your primary DNS server? Does the slow loading happen every time? or just sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out Google's DNS Service: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using
Set this Service as your DNS in your network adapter settings.

Comment: These are what I use.

Answer (score -1):

> What should I try next?

You should try *diagnosing your problem*.  `schlomm`'s answer is a good example of just floundering about at random, in the hope that something works.  So, too, are your actions in your question.  Maybe you'll accidentally hit the locus of the problem.  But as you've experienced, one usually does not and there is a *lot* of floundering.

`schlomm`'s answer is also a good example of another sin: assuming that the DNS is somehow the cause without any evidence whatsoever.  (A third sin is unthinkingly handing over the complete control of all of one's name→address lookups to a company financed by selling you to advertisers.)

WWW browsers such as Firefox and Google Chrome have "developer tools" that let one see exactly what the browser is doing at each stage of the long and complex process that is the loading and display of a WWW page, only a part of which is even DNS-related at all.

Pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in (Windows) Google Chrome brings up the developer tools, for example, where on the "Network" tab there's a timeline of what item was fetched from what URL, and how much time was spent in the individual parts of each HTTP transaction.  Google Chrome's developer tools just told me that the 2 seconds that it took to fully load https://superuser.com/questions on one of my computers were almost entirely down to waiting 2 seconds for the WWW servers at http://www.gravatar.com/ to respond to an HTTP request for one person's user icon.

Look at what these tools tell you, and *find the locus of the problem*.  Diagnose your problem *before* attempting to fix it.  It may not even be your problem to fix in the first place.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004).  [*Prove that your problem really is a DNS problem.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-narrow-problem-locus.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003).  [*All your *.COM./*.NET. are belong to us.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/verisign-internet-coup.html).  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: It's not a problem with other sites. They load just fine with other computers. I think what I have been doing is diagnosing. I just told I have tried to locate the problem with different network cards, cables etc.

Comment: What you have been doing is **replacing parts at random** based upon no evidence that those parts are faulty in any way, which is hope and guesswork at best and most certainly **not** diagnosis.  It's not fault diagnosis when a mechanic does it to a mechanical system, and it's not fault diagnosis when you do it to your computer.  This is why the world of engineering **has** diagnostic tools, like the ones in Chrome.  Use them, and stop floundering around randomly!